# C++ how to manage clean up of a dynamically allocate object that also dynamically allocates memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a class `Aclass` which contains a pointer to struct `GraphStructure *Graph_`.

The `Aclass` constructor initializes this pointer by dynamically allocating a `GraphStructure` instance.

The `GraphStructure` instance also dynamically allocates arrays and calls delete on these in its destructor.

The order in which the destructors are called are (1) the class destructor and (2) the struct destructor.

If I call `delete` on `Graph_` in the `Aclass` destructor and then the destructor for the struct is called, is there a double free happening here as my  program stops responding.

If I don't call `delete Graph_;` then it runs ok but am I not introducing a memory leak here?
What is the correct way to handle this?

I've tried to debug the program.

```
struct GraphStructure
{
    idx_t* xadj;                     
    idx_t* adjncy;                    

    GraphStructure() {

        xadj = new idx_t[5]; 
        adjncy = new idx_t[5];

    }   

    ~GraphStructure() {
        delete[] xadj;
        delete[] adjncy;
    }
};


class Aclass 
{
    GraphStructure *Graph_;
 }



Aclass::Aclass():Graph_(new GraphStructure()) {}

Aclass::~Aclass()
{
//delete Graph_;
}
```

Comment: Don't use naked `new`, use smart pointers instead. Or `std::vector` for arrays.

Comment: Use smart pointers and containers instead of managing memory allocation yourself.

Comment: Also, the premise of the question is wrong. If you do `delete Graph_` in `~Aclass` there is no double free in itself. The problem likely comes from incorrect copy constructors. Read up on the rule of five and the rule of zero. Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: explicit use of `new` `delete` is not recommended nowadays. See this: https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE